# Declare variable as function value at a given time - not the function itself

Tags: javascript, function, variables, handsontable

I am trying to declare a variable with the value returned by a function:

```
var myValue = hot.getSettings();
```

However, the value of myValue keeps changing when the return value of getSettings() change. How can I define myValue as the **current** value of the getSettings() function, and save that value in myValue, even if getSettings change?

Comment: What exactly does `getSettings` return…?

Comment: do you return value from hot.getSettings() and did you print what does it return?

Comment: getSettings is the getSettings-function declared in Handsontable. It saves the current settings of a handsontable instance. What I'm trying to do is save the current instance - but what i've saved keeps changing. http://docs.handsontable.com/0.16.1/Core.html#getSettings

Comment: You want to make a copy of the object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: @user2806026 You're downvoting answers which you think are not answering your question, but not upvoting the answer which you have marked as the accepted answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem it that hot.getSettings(); return a reference not a copy of variable
So you just need to clone that variable

try this :

```
var value = hot.getSettings();
var myValue = $.extend(true, {}, value);
```

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using Handsontable, you can use its helpers to do that real quick:

```
var snapshot = Handsontable.helper.deepClone(hot.getSettings());
```

This way you'll create a deep clone of the settings object, which should not be referencing the original one anymore.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to conserve different values that the function `hot.getSettings()` might return you need to store them somewhere,

for ex an Array:

```
var arr = []
var myValue = arr[0]

arr.push(hot.getSettings());//push returns the length , and you could use that for naming a key in an object if needed
```

Comment: That is exactly what I started out doing, but the value in the array keeps changing..

Comment: @user2806026 if you return something that points to another-something , whenever another-something changes also something will change; if this is your situation the easiest solution is [making a copy of the return object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript?noredirect=1&lq=1)